# Section header titles messed up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a table view controller with sections. The section title normally appear as such:

[image]

However, sometimes they get messed up - duplicated, overlaid on top of a table cell:

[image]

I can't figure out exactly when it's happening other than it seems to happen only occasionally when I segue back from a detail view controller.

I'm not even sure where to start the debugging or what code to paste into this post. Therefore, I'm not asking to pinpoint the problem, but as a start:

- Has anybody experienced something similar? If so, what were the root causes?
- Where should I start looking for the issue? What are the typical culprits? `willDisplayHeaderView`? Or for example not doing a `tableView.reloadData()` at a specific location?

Comment: Did you check if the cell height is correctly calculated/specified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how the `headerSection` is set, this is happened after you reload your table. Could put your code on the question?